# How To Display Images Preview and Title When I Paste in Another Site Like Facebook, Whatsapp, etc

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, url

I tried copying another site's news 
[this is image when i copy one of the url news](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwmbP.png)
then I paste it in whatsapp then it appears like this [this is image when i after paste in whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9xLx.png) this is so good

but when i copy one of the url my project news [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl9hs.png) and then i paste in whatsapp but it will be like this [this is image after i paste in whatsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ4hC.png) it will not be like the previous picture, there is no title and preview image

thanks,

Comment: Google `meta tags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site isn't using meta tags. which is basically looks like this.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title">
<meta property="og:description" content="Description">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/index.htm">
```

Google about meta for learn in details and how to use.